# Spring boot | JPA - Internal Server Error, Expected "identifier"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

So I have 3 entities Client, Inventory, and Order. But whenever I try to create a new Client, this error shows up.

```
Could not write JSON: could not prepare statement [Syntax error in SQL statement "select o1_0.client_id,o1_0.id,o1_0.inventory_id,i1_0.id,i1_0.base64data,i1_0.category,i1_0.name,i1_0.price,i1_0.stock,o1_0.quantity,o1_0.sub_total,o1_0.total from [*]order o1_0 left join inventory i1_0 on i1_0.id=o1_0.inventory_id where o1_0.client_id=?"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: select o1_0.client_id,o1_0.id,o1_0.inventory_id,i1_0.id,i1_0.base64data,i1_0.category,i1_0.name,i1_0.price,i1_0.stock,o1_0.quantity,o1_0.sub_total,o1_0.total from order o1_0 left join inventory i1_0 on i1_0.id=o1_0.inventory_id where o1_0.client_id=? [42001-214]] [select o1_0.client_id,o1_0.id,o1_0.inventory_id,i1_0.id,i1_0.base64data,i1_0.category,i1_0.name,i1_0.price,i1_0.stock,o1_0.quantity,o1_0.sub_total,o1_0.total from order o1_0 left join inventory i1_0 on i1_0.id=o1_0.inventory_id where o1_0.client_id=?]
```

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Name should have atleast 2 characters")
    private String fullname;
    @Size(min=10, message = "Contact Number should have atleast 10 characters")
    private String contactNumber;
    @Email(message = "Email should be a valid email")
    private String email;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Address should have atleast 2 characters")
    private String address;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("client")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("client")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Patient> patients;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("client")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Order> orders;
```

```
@Entity
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Product Name should have atleast 2 characters")
    private String name;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Category should have atleast 2 characters")
    private String category;
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Stock should have a minimum of 1 value")
    private Integer stock;
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Price should have a minimum of 1 value")
    private Float price;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String base64Data;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("inventory")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "inventory")
    private List<Order> orders;
```

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Quantity should have a minimum value of 1")
    private Integer quantity;
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Sub Total should have a minimum value of 1")
    private Float subTotal;
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Total should have a minimum value of 1")
    private Float total;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("orders")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id", nullable = false)
    private Inventory inventory;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("orders")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
```

So, the general flow would be that a client can take multiple orders that have multiple single instances of inventory in each order hence why it is ManyToOne. Each Order has one instance of a Client.

Comment: Please add always the complete stacktrace

Comment: `order` is a keyword in sql. rename the table

Comment: @Jens it worked! didn't even realize order is a keyword. Thank you!